# Print the last, middle and first character of your code

Tags: code-golf, self-referential

The challenge is simple: Print the last, middle, and first character of your program's source code, in that order.

The middle character is defined as follows, assuming a source length of `n` characters, and 1-indexing:

- If `n` is even, print the `n/2`-th and `n/2 + 1`-th character. (`abcdef == cd`)
- If `n` is odd, print `(n-1)/2 + 1`-th character. (`abcde == c`)

#### Rules

- Given no input, print the last, middle, and first character in your source code, in the form `[last][middle][first]`. This will be 3-4 characters long.
- Output must not contain any trailing whitespace. However, if whitespace is a first, middle, or last character, it must be printed as such.
- Source code must be `n >= 3` characters long.
- Code must consist of `>= 3` unique characters.
- [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution *in characters* wins.

#### Samples

```
# Form: [code] --> [output]
xyz --> zyx
abcd --> dbca
1 --> # not allowed: too short
abcde --> eca
aaabb --> # not allowed: not enough unique characters
System.out.print("S;pr"); --> ;prS
this is a test --> ts t
123[newline]45 --> 53[newline]1
```

[Challenge Proposal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17866/77309)

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=188005;
var OVERRIDE_USER=78850;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but "Code must consist of >= 3 unique characters." suggests all characters of the program should be unique, while you only require to have at least 3 distinct characters.

Comment: I also think codes should be allowed to have few unique characters. I'd love to see a whitespace answer, it might even have a newline in the output

Comment: @Belhenix Fewer than three unique characters allows solutions as simple as `121` for a great many languages.

Comment: If anyone can find a stack-based language that uses `-` for negation and implicitly prints with a linefeed, `\n1-` is a three-byter. My search has so far been fruitless.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki That bit means you can't cheese the challenge by having an answer like `aba`, which is 2 unique characters. However, `abc` or `aabc` would be allowed.

Comment: @Belhenix Whitespace is certainly possible, it has enough unique valid characters (space, linefeed, tab).

Comment: @bigyihsuan got it. I sympathize with the rule. I just make a minor remark that the wording of the rule is not fully precise.

Comment: Just type `1231` into a python interpreter...

Comment: @bigyihsuan, `aabc` definitely doesn't contain `>= 3` unique characters. It contains two unique characters and one duplicated one.

Comment: Can't change it now with 58 answers, but requiring "first letter of code must be different from last letter of code" would have ruled out a **lot** of trivial answers, including the current top answer. That may have been the intent of ">= 3 unique characters", but that requirement isn't actually very hard.

Comment: Your second from the last sample output looks wrong.  "this is a test --> s tt"

Comment: @James Seems to be the case. Need to change that...

Answer (score 202):

## JavaScript, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```javascript
N=>a=-N
```

Outputs: `NaN`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@9/P1i7RVtfvf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

Comment: Very clever. This was the tact I was trying to take, but just couldn't stumble upon a language with curt enough error output.

Comment: This is one of the best Javascript answers I've ever seen here

Comment: I saw javascript and got shocked. Then I read the actual solution and laughed much harder than I should have. Congratulations!!

Answer (score 23):

## [Grass](https://github.com/TryItOnline/grass), 17 bytes

```
wWWwwwVVwWWwWWWww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788PLy8vDwsDESHg9j//wMA)

-2 bytes thanks to jimmy23013.

Outputs `www`. Grass ignores all characters apart from `w`, `W` and `v`. The two `V`s are thus ignored; they are there to ensure the middle character is a `w` – I have no idea how to output `v` or `W` in Grass… I could have used another character instead of `V`, but `V` preserves the aesthetic of the code.

Comment: "_Luckily, the middle character ended up being a w and not a v or a W – I have no idea how to output v or W in Grass…_" Lol. xD I tried to do something similar in Whitespace having also only three characters (space, tab, newline), but unfortunately [I wasn't so lucky..](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188031/52210) Luckily I can simply add a bunch of trailing no-ops to fix it, though.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen If the middle character had been anything else, I would probably have added in the middle a bunch of `x`s (or any other non-Grass character, which Grass ignores) to move a `w` into the correct place.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot.. I can insert a non-whitespace character as well which Whitespace will ignore. ;) -2 bytes thanks to you.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788PLy8vFxBAUSHg9j//wMA): `wWWwww  wWWwWWWww`

Comment: @jimmy23013 Thanks! And thanks for posting [your tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188109/86301); I needed it to understand what you did! I changed the spaces to `V`s because I find it prettier. ;-)

Answer (score 21):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 17 bytes

```
U-[>+<-UU--]>...U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/VDfaTttGNzRUVzfWTk9PL/T/fwA)

With unprintables this can be reduced to 7 bytes: `␀..␀_.␀`

Comment: Within the rules, but BF doesn't use `U` as an instruction. Functionally,the code is `-[>+<---]>.`, so the expected output would be `.--`, which it does not output.

Comment: @bigyihsuan but the source code still contains the `U`s and this interpreter happily ignores them. Should every answer which has comments or multiple spaces (or anything else that doesn't necessarily matter to the language) be not counted?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `U-[>+<-UU--]>...U`? In its current form the code only shows one U

Comment: @Helena thanks for catching that.

Comment: @dzaima: There is an ongoing argument that golfing entails minimizing code to the smallest viable product, thus inherently disallowing comments or ignored characters. I'm on the fence about it. While I usually err on the side of allowing comments in general, it feels less okay to do so for quines as the challenge is in the code. This answer effectively avoids the "middle character of the code" requirement by artificially shifting the middle character.

Comment: @Flater "disallowing comments or ignored characters" doesn't follow from "minimizing code to the smallest viable product". Very often it may be the case, but here (and in many other answers in many other challenges) it is 
 most definitely not. Noone's advocating disallowing comments in general (or I would hope so), only when they obviously don't help golfiness.

Comment: @dzaima: It's a matter of conforming to the rules of the challenge. The reason they're generally allowed is because they generally are only to the detriment of an entry (byte count wise - the predominant challenge measure). In other challenges they may even be desirable (e.g. involving ASCII art). However, here they're being used to pretty much circumvent a key requirement of the challenge (it must be the middle character which is also printed). This is different from the usual challenges and here it avoids part of the challenge.

Comment: @Flater Yes, here they're used to make the challenge easier, but isn't that the whole purpose of the [tag:code-golf] tag? Many answers here alone make their job easier by adding leading/trailing whitespace, and in general in code-golf here anything following the rules is allowed (and if I had to guess, if there was a rule disallowing unused characters (defining which objectively would already be pretty much impossible) would mean that the challenge might be still hovering at 0 score, and probably be closed as well).

Comment: Why don't you simply use `ÿ-.ÿ..ÿ`? That's printable and short.

Answer (score 18):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 119 bytes

```
 ,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]
Ajax:  You big big big big big cat.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fQUfPMSuxQkcvIDE9FchOLlHwtNILTk7NSwUxol3zSlKLFEBKFBLzUhRAqmK5QFwrBYXI/FKFpMx0DJycWKIXXJCamK1QklGJlaXw/z8A)

Prints three spaces. Without printing spaces:

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 227 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:You is the sum of a big big big big big big cat a big pig.
You is the sum of you a large huge large big pig.
Speak thy.Speak thy.You is the sum of you a big pig.Speak thy.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXfNKUosUQEoUEvNSFECqYkE8q8j8UoXMYoWSjFSF4tJchfw0hUSFpMx0rDg5sQQqW5CZrseFqbUSKJKokJNYlJ6qkFEKJCBMuI7ggtTEbKCGSj0EC5cpME0Ilf//AwA)

Like my newline-free INTERCAL answer, this is constructed to make the last character of the program the same as the middle character (although in this case it is not also the first), by un-golfing the second half of the code until they match. (I'm not sure if I could have constructed 46 in fewer bytes or not, or if I could have golfed other parts of the first half more.)

Comment: I wasn't expecting Shakespeare to show up for this. This is great

Comment: Wish I could +1 just for learning this language existed!

Comment: @Stilez It's actually not that uncommon on here. There's a whole [tag:tips] page on it (which I copy-pasted the program header from)

Comment: even in the online interpreter's debug output messages, the authors' sense of humor shows: **Warning at line 2: 'mind' expected**

Comment: [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f/fSUfPMSuxQkcvIDE9FchOLlHwtNILTk7NSwUxol3zSlKLFEBKFBLzUhRAqmJBPKvI/FKFzGKFkoxUheLSXIX8NIVEhaTMdAUnIE5CwsmJJUAZIKkXXJCamA3UUKmHqbcSKALECDWKwQGujt4KIR6Riv//AwA "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online") for the second version by ending with a `!`

Comment: @RobinRyder I think that's substantially different enough in how it shows actual understanding of the language that it deserves to be its own answer. Go forth and reap the reputation, you've earned it

Comment: @UnrelatedString OK, thanks! [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188495/86301).

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```python
print' t'
```

To make the whitespace clear:

```python
$ xxd solution.py
0000000: 0a70 7269 6e74 2720 7427 20           .print' t'
$ python2 solution.py | xxd
0000000: 2074 0a                                t.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/n6ugKDOvRF0BiP7/BwA)

<sub>-2 bytes, thanks to wastl !</sub>

Comment: Both output trailing whitespace (newline), which is not allowed. Python 2 alternative: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/n6ugKDOvRF0BiP7/BwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, I don't think this is valid: Python requires you to have an empty newline at the end of your code.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi As I understand it, a newline at the end of the source code is just a recommendation. See PEP8.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi [Just a guideline](https://www.gofcr.com/wp-content/upload/2017/08/pirates.jpg)

Comment: @wastl Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ RR
```

Outputs `R \n`.

-2 bytes by taking inspiration from [*@Neil*'s Batch answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188022/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@f61HDPIWgoP//AQ)

**5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative by *@Grimy*:**

```
12,1
```

Outputs `12\n`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@fy9BIx/D/fwA)

**Initial 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
'?„«'«?
```

Outputs `?«'`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3f5Rw7xDq9UPrbb//x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
          # No-op newline
„ R       # Push 2-char string " R"
   R      # Reverse this string to "R "
          # (output the result implicitly with trailing newline)

          # No-op newline
12,       # Print 12 with trailing newline
   1      # Push a 1 (no implicit printing, since we already did an explicit print)

'?       '# Push 1-char string "?"
  „«'    '# Push 2-char string "«'"
     «    # Concatenate them both together
      ?   # Output without trailing newline
```

Comment: [Alternative 5](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@fy9DI1vD/fwA)

Answer (score 10):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9@Qy@D/fwA)

I think this is valid?

Comment: I'm guessing `1` and `0` are pushed onto a stack, then an implicit pop-print at the end of the program?

Yes it's valid

Comment: @bigyihsuan that's what I'm guessing too; I don't know the language, I just recall it does stuff like this :p

Comment: @dzaima Haha, when you post an answer and you don't even know how it works. xD I've indeed seen RProgN a few times before with old `[quine]` challenges, before the quine-rules got changed.

Comment: I believe this is polyglot in [`tac`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) on Linux.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
001 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/AwFDB4P9/AA)

The output has two distinct characters, but the code also has a third one.

Trivial 4-byte version:

```
1231
```

Comment: Isn't `121` also a valid trivial answer?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: No, because it has only two distinct characters

Answer (score 8):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 9 bytes

```php
<?=";;<";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WydraRsn6/38A)

Comment: Actually, since PHP outputs code as text until the first `<?` tag, you could use one of the trivial 4-byte solutions like `1231` - anything without a special character as first and last, any other 2 characters in the middle. Your answer may be the shortest *real code* PHP answer.

Answer (score 8):

## Excel, 9 bytes

```
=("))=" )
```

So many Parentheses.

Note: The returned middle character can actually be any character since it's the middle of the code.

Comment: Parentheses!  (Lightbulb)  I got stuck with the last character needing to be `"`.  Well done!

Comment: Thanks! It was something I was trying to figure out as well, and then I remembered that parentheses would work.

Answer (score 7):

## DOS/Windows Batch Language, 9 bytes

```
@echo @o@
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf & Coding Challenges Stack Exchange, +1 for nice first post!

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 9 characters

```
@echo hh
```

The middle and last character are both `h`, and then the `echo` prints a newline by default, which is the first character of the script.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 6 bytes

```ruby
p " "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/n6tAQUlB6f9/AA)

This outputs `" "` plus a newline. The code ends with a `"`, the middle two characters are  and `"`, and it starts with a newline.

Comment: I like your badge, I believe it's a grayscale xor on N². I generated almost the same picture to help me for a Project Euler Nim problem. Does your badge have a story?

Comment: Nice catch! I just like "doodling" during meetings by generating pictures using one-liners; xor was an early favorite.

Answer (score 6):

## PowerShell, 3 bytes

```
00000000: 0a0d 31                                  ..1
```

Works only in Microsoft Windows.

The output is unfortunately 8 bytes in UTF-16. But the question says output the characters, and not the bytes. Arguably UTF-16 is just one of the supported ways to represent the characters in PowerShell. They are not interpreted differently from an ASCII file.

Comment: it's smart answer

Comment: allowed because `0x0a != 0x0d != 0x31` :)

Answer (score 6):

### Bash (<strike>15</strike> 11 characters)

```
echo -n e-e
```

which prints out

```
e-e
```

- -4 chars by not using `|rev`

Comment: @racraman Your suggested edit of `echo<space>e<space><space>e` will output `e<space>e<newline>` instead of `e<space>e`, so I've rejected it. The newline is part of the output, which is why _GrzegorzOledzki_ is using the `-n` option. [Try `echo -n e-e` online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN08hVTf1/38A) vs [Try `echo e  e` online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hVUEh9f9/AA). And again, please don't edit other peoples answer. If you have a golf to suggest, leave a comment.

Comment: also 11 bytes with `printf  pfp`, but only because we need two spaces due to that definition of middle character, otherwise it would be 10 ...

Answer (score 6):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), <s>9 bytes</s> 7 bytes

Thanks to [Khuldraeseth na'Barya](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/khuldraeseth-nabarya) for the improved solution!

```
W(SSW)S
```

As for as I can tell, this is now unimprovable since:

- The first character has to be a no-op character, since every other instruction raises an error due to the stack being empty, with the exception being an opening bracket. However, it can't be that since there is no way to output an opening bracket on it's own in Underload.
- You need to use at least 5 characters to add the 3 output characters to the stack.
- You need to use S to output it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f8/XCM4OFwz@P9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! You can save a couple bytes by skipping the copy, [like so](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f8/XCM4OFwz@P9/AA).

Answer (score 6):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>163</s> 153 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Jo King.

```
B,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:You is
the sum ofa Big Big Big BIG BIG cat a
CAT.Speak thy.You is twice you.Speak thy!SPEAK THY!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYuxDoIwGIR3nuLYSR@ADQxR4kJSFmIc/tRfqEpLbBvl6avVgeGS73LfueURY12I6kbvQnQ08peVR1sKqdhwglNjPD@RFJC5IFnn1MrBBmiX@Ynhwgx7JdR63NLuf1HkQdmu6oVcmO7w0yr@V/iXVozVhm3KZddUR/SHIY/xAw)

My first SPL answer! Outputs `!BB`.

There is [another](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188082/86301) SPL answer by Unrelated String; in that answer, they output only spaces in 119 bytes, or output non-space characters in 227 bytes. This one comes in between, and also outputs non-space characters.

Two tricks are used here:

1. An SPL sentence can end with `!` rather than `.`, and `!` is easier to get since its ASCII codepoint is 33 (=\$2^5+1\$), whereas the codepoint of `.` is 46.
2. Doubling 33 gives 66, the codepoint of `B`, hence the play title is `B` and I need the second "big" to be "Big", which works since SPL is case-insensitive.

Since I needed that capital `B` and an exclamation mark at the end, I decided to have Ajax shout louder and louder through the scene.

Answer (score 6):

It feels cheaty, but

## [Mornington Crescent](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent), 1005 bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Euston









Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Gunnersbury
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Gunnersbury
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Tottenham Hale
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Gunnersbury
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Leicester Square
Take Northern Line to Leicester Square
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

There are nine deliberately placed newlines after the first instruction to make the middle character the `o` of `Take District Line to Upminster`. The code prints out the first three characters of `Tottenham Hale` reversed to yield `toT`. Of course, this challenge was made easier by the fact that Mornington Crescent programs always start with the `T` of `Take` and end with the `t` of `Mornington Crescent`, barring any extra newlines. 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNBTgMxDEX3nCIX4BAwIFgMCGkK@xAsxurkp3gcUE9fXApBMFRNmSzzX@xvx45JwHjWhNMgNAaCbjYLvyR3m0R7EriWQU6Tu8yjYSflfFAPHDQJ@0J19EpwHY9KMu5hvi52csMSBqoTzz2WfwrXPkZLGFn7nX5hDsRCFeIqA0Y8ZlnvISYxfuVoPJCsNhUirXNxdIQZBd6vImPb9tryjo5wSD/c4p@fOxmMRVIl9D6a2YHmT88/HJ7Ze5iRN1QCdxyCf@JhWH@XkQUrNq31oJlUSxxo23PXvWQvn@BkOSuxm7Lurinr/g4)

Comment: I've just realized that this works in TIO (Esoterpret) but not in Esoteric IDE.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```ruby
print:ptp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM6/EqqCk4P9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 61 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "D I"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzKy89JSf7/3zNEPVgh2MM/PMTT15UrxNHHWyHEXyHEw1XBw9HPRUHJRcFTiSvSPxTIDXNVcHJ19VMIcQ3y9fRzDHF1@f8fAA)

Trivial answer in ArnoldC. The 31st byte is the space just before the string literal.

Answer (score 5):

## [Chef](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Acme-Chef/), 447 bytes

```
Last Middle First Milkshake.

This recipe prints its last, middle and first character.
You could also use it to make a milkshake. 

Ingredients.
76 ml milk
32 ml chocolate syrup
46 teaspoons vanilla ice cream

Method.
Liquefy vanilla ice cream.
Put the milk into 1st mixing bowl.
Put the chocolate syrup into 1st mixing bowl.
Put the vanilla ice cream into 1st mixing bowl.
Pour contents of the 1st mixing bowl into the 1st baking dish.

Serves 1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHdSgMxEIXv8xTnAWShKvUNBKEFQW@8nCazzdBsZs1PtU@/ZrcUoUW8CCSc882ZmVjP/TRtKBdsxbnAeJa0PMIhezpwZ8y7l4zEVkbGmCSWDGknNOgOw5mi6NAvpPWUyBZOnfnQCqs1OFDIipq5gSiKoRUGNfYSAmNe4j6xE27lO/O0xhAW3Tzcz1fr1WqgwsinVEfzuEZhyqNqzDhSlBAIYhk2MQ3GbLl4dZ3ZyGfl/nRr6cxrbb14XlLQplKsWvuDfEvcY6df4ddylf6P@ybrL7/W1PYTyzwztF/gK9cZvQg7OsyCk@zbv7xxOnLGqpumHw)

## A serious submission, <del>196</del> 177 bytes

### thanks to A__

```
R.

Ingredients.
82 l a
103 l b
46 l c

Method.
Put a into mixing bowl.
Put b into mixing bowl.
Put c into mixing bowl.
Pour contents of mixing bowl into baking dish.

Serves 1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NCsIwEIX3c4o5QbAqxSu4EERPkJ9pM1gzkEzV26cp3bjQ1Qffe/CejzTUejMA5zRmCkxJi4HTHie00O0OjQ6OfYMHuJBGCQaus6JFTir45A@nEZ28p827P97/8jJn9JJ0XUUZvtOt7uxjFYFLbB/vlF9UsDO1Lg)

Comment: Seeing Chef programs makes me wonder what is the bare minimum for it.

Comment: @bigyihsuan see my edit

Comment: You can remove all the "the"'s and make the program still [work](https://tio.run/##dY5NCsIwEIX3c4o5QSAggkdwURA9QX6mzWCdkSRVb5@mdONCVx9878F7IdHY2pUCP8kAnGXKFJmkFgMnnNGBtbbTw@HYEQAGqkmjgctS0SFLVXzwh2VCr@959/6PD7@8LhmDSt1GUcfvdK97d99E5JL6xRvlFxW0prUV).

Comment: I [created](https://tio.run/##dY5NCsIwEIX3c4o5QbAqxSu4EERPkJ9pM1gzkEzV26cp3bjQ1Qffe/CejzTUejMA5zRmCkxJi4HTHie00O0OjQ6OfYMHuJBGCQaus6JFTir45A@nEZ28p827P97/8jJn9JJ0XUUZvtOt7uxjFYFLbB/vlF9UsDO1Lg) a working program. (177 bytes)

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, 3 bytes

```
i+1
```

`i` represents the imaginary number.

Answer (score 5):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 7 bytes

```
O"OO"O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCey4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJLcfwBeELIPqZNknybAcIX89193zopEtcpe7pVKWNfN0T/czPd09TtS/jaLvr5IsSlfTeK8op8ni9d24bY6kyU1tKCofl/EaKE@y29pQmcwFZhrPkixmacrSRXZLH209@un08wc2qF4vPp0zv3r928E5261ej07fsV@q1/PPbFCBj04uDOzp5xMD@vn0w8HFX@2CMxs/uuzb4C9czx5cwLJiMroLc@bwSsBEga1axXjMdqu508PfcTKDSfLoK8Pve3trGFyGMOgmYNKUI7CGeXt2dkIg/NgnJ4fom2HI@XsBAHnD1vswXcWcX2YT3m6TH7Arl5PgvHN4dmR/b591zuDfdw5vnZEAOICIwzkLEDpqt0HfMsyL2Obsqd1KspIlo3YLRkm3y5zZKotghIQjeC/nS7dYZpf@JHjyXO8ZdLQSUEd4eHo48OYNqk@W7OEuKeNiGUZxuwXf09iGcRC3hRku61yVV9nV7CpnT8@XE5sPX3U4mdJKZszW1gbMemVxJlSo0S0YvcpguNcTI2BnK06L2Bx4FuZEd3H0DzZb5CxbzW/ivJD2MDsppsltUiqtsDq6M3C1R@LpsIHHesyRlvd6nPWZ5VmwBFqacJbH5SrPmIoGIUYBMVq34T7Mk/AmjZUVYES6eIhzO4L1lCHs61emjIvoLSIivlhc0pM0uJ4EAxf2KNDDa9bh@ZJxCJBsulrauKVMctpn8LZpsDjthdAmzLiyrMqmjiU2DYTBA20UAyWQHeA7WLYMi5KVdzEoC/MSwHIDHMUobmjE0RNlrHFoXjQWPgecNrpVkUHmY@iWySIDszFivQmYFilGitVyiYRzFVVqxKTfjD@g3SAbdahQXmYQx5CpMHKl5YKVT5Y@zmLgCAcwaw0xW6GZKsgo0QlXbbQbTQ3TdBHZu5474OggDmsnyMFslaZh/mg6Wu3PubE9Hy1tGS0o5VfZmjQtMcAlZFJo8vTg8O2769@2Tn49@2Z4bOq9SRoV@5uKt2qa3x9fvKCxjHNSGWZT9s9VqF5R7b25xM7mEoKB95Ym47iBDBLerQvXMc@UK/NVhls0kunWKReFrZIlnQCI7TKJGM3erGaX/u5E2iF2ukv5QRtQLOFclTMboOD/dppOOyrxULlxUcm6AjgVWoEoZGL9Gm6PDXbqfqLzGIz7rFPmq7gDQajHMSZhfBZCCsGJDoZWpyIB/UTfZcUhOr68XSxSmLmpM/Cir5VbP3LI@XmPTDNvNsxM0cbsT7URgrZcpKltmuoyz4US8T@YnG2YjGX4w8HHUxeLsQg0eD2@HHieB@EErsCreiuSf8VfSoaPkRGjhrfIALy5@OHT504wUDUdUxyWdXzQpy8eOwA4Oj45dNgMsuOopUNbrod5OAqXbhpn1AIYXKmGSHAG5@4lMtYFsThhbcOKYyfUTEAx3iMuRlBVEpzUeSOaL9d2gEhKJlUKQZqSCS5TPCRldGc7wMxG/wQcMfkXYaGyDqwhw1UEIEBCsQODNMy75JRUL3vAWsjyEZXhCkGNZplj7aJe83LCn6owgw6KkrtY@BwWruvOIePZvOv9McO/CvkRkKBVcHQblym0iXaX9rKLO4Q1cppkfJTMbJv2EzuC6C5HW1yIU87FNgfeqNFWeHDqA8R6h2I90TpiNpCEjJS9SJLMnZWVbyt/BF7PvKtmUNKkWGOuAYPRAPEXLBfLOLONhd1O3qFeAawK5qJUQjwGvrf7C43L7sIWLckMTJ@iU9DDQci62OABHJoHesM1YGkVXjYMsl5AvRCeWEBySTfoobWIatTgBMw3m5aKxsqT38CT@A/o4/C0b/i5Vdt1ug1sYSbbAJ5shAesktZ5MeC/WkPZKDYEss58sgJ1TqkvtrEGcVWExuNdXnWWG@lQiV5Qd2hvFyhYPwybwkAn9D7mupBJeaeCqgksL3GYSbUvlTBZs8wdkLlFsnBWsYAHQ9x8kDSxnzXqWLdLV6h@H6ET0edeUb/dUmZtv3YKsMeGN87UUcsN81dloXZfxwQ2e9Kebxub2G@Mip62m9IppFXM3BiBxi6KrrtV1yeurYiG@wFTyn2hHPtkOjNinwiFw5gMAkWGz5sjOgpL9ZDd6aBXscnVd9TFoWt16VnKVCL96m/4b7iPLX3dXiHkVJvYwMJ6FW/gwdngQWx/EwvzBtccwgSmEhKAUmVTIg2sK7gMImjU75M@SRRV1vV4EIyWtSTx5ofEvGkmZvuHQtvNQn8nNmsOiSsGjfmmlyNJu2A9YP2BZpmwQP0AjmN/AEdxYIL9n0TvQRatYYMAobTuUI14inIi2h97kmufU1fjBMR/e/1A0CS5AlcJysNYieA73izu4jy2CpYtoNVO0jLJ2EP4CLyx6QLurmV8G@cgs1xkcVYmIV424MAv2EPM7sL7GIBSEcJLNg@zFYTP42scRe9ukHGggpgoVmmJPy7Q4jovKkjfxKgl1ygz5TRkTT3qexnpvWyIhu3VUB7d48MUS@gjeJ1N03jKriuzr7WWJ/wm@jdjkcqZMSrr99U7J3hLQh3D9GfdeexRsK7VR0x6tbwY1LPiPjMP/555DFB0KH@Q6zIB2Ge1fpIGXWZkQ9ThCUlVmX1RLhC7FUBRMpqlMRxKDK3FdDFk83geLTHMMja@3v9/XRn/Ca6MlStbDb4E0hfpyv7L7ItVG0zG6X1WA/ga4as6u9VkZ/Wi3VOZx1SgzetW6Q99aaoN@6akTCVa/ut/Iy9zkKFGy4@soYmudcPr2KDKuvXpn77vqBa4uvAgrlW79OhUSBjUOAlq0kaaRAlE9HpaTJj8O7gnfh0z@9Gad6yhxTmuN/cINeT3/eGOQct7cbMIjEasZxagzatUJu8nrj4LO7W@90IQvaZ0tF7y/KaSt8N1H@Br6V0a/A8NERqGT9yKSN8RdDtk9kY@eIir9gbYJFGDIOJfTNKDED15EmD1aTwLIUmCZ6oRTTKYTKb0W1MYlVCmrO3IwtYURzh74bKLynQNhG5Q/t4wD5MMe1oW5reRS0odB77fc/xVi66h@P87tkfW1G97z9//DQ)

Prints `OO<newline>`.

Whitespace is ignored, `O` is monadic output function which prints the string `"OO"` without quotes and a trailing newline, and the last `O` is ignored because the parsing ends at `O"OO"`.

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 7 bytes

```
O-1 2-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLSeS4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJLcfwBeELIPqZNknybAcIX89193zopEtcpe75YPlGT3d0/1MT3ePiQa3UfT9VZJF6Woa7xXlNFm8vhu3zZk0ualNReXjMl4D5Ul2W5sqk7nATONZksUsTVm6yG7po61nP51@/sC8anjx6Zz51fBvB@dstxoenb5jv1TD88/Mq8BHJxcG9vTziQH9fPrh4OKvdsGZjR9d9s37C9dvDy5gWfEyugtz1uOVgIkCW7WK8ZjtVu9OD3/Hlxm8JI@@Mvy@t7eGwWUIg24CJk05AmuYt2dnJwTCj31ycoi@GYacvxcAkDdsvQ/TVcz5ZTbh7Tb5AbtyOQnOO4dnR/b39tnAY/7gO4dRZyQAPUDE4ZwFCB2126BvGeZFbHP21G4lWcmSUbsFs6TbYb3ZKotghoQjGJfzpVMss0t/Ejy5jvsMOloJqCM8PF2cePMG1SdL9nCXlHGxDKO43YLvaWzDPIjbwgyHda7Kq@xqdpWzp@fLic2HrzqcTGklM2ZrawNmvbI4EyrU7BbMXmUw3e@LGbCzFadFbE48C3Oiuzj6B5stcpat5jdxXkh7mJ0U0@Q2KZVWWB3d8RztkXj2mOeyPutJy/t9zgbMci1YAi1NOMvjcpVnTEWDEKOAGK3bcB/mSXiTxsoKMCJdPMS5HcF6yhD29StTxkU0ioiILxaX9CQNrieB58AeBXp6zTo8XzIOAZJNV0sbt5RJTgcMRpsGi9NeCG3CjCvLqmzqWGLTQBg80EYxUALZAb6DZcuwKFl5F4OyMC8BLDegpxjFDY04eqKMNQ7Ni8bCp8dpo1sVGWQ@hm6ZLDIwGyPWnYBpkWKkWC2XSDhXUaVmTPrN@APaDbJRhwrlZQZxDJkKI1daLlj5ZOnjLCaOcAKz1hCzFZqpgowSnXDVRrvR1DBNF5G96zoeRwdxWjtBDmarNA3zR9PRan/Oje35aGnLaEEpv8rWpGkJD5eQSaHJ04PDt@@uf9s6@fXsm@GxqfcmaVTsbyreqml@f3zxgsYyzkllmE3ZP1ehGqLae3OJnc0lBAPvLU3GcQMZJLxbF65jnilX5qsMt2gk022vXBS2SpZ0AiC2yyRi9PZmNbv0dyfSDrHTXcoP2oBiCeeqnNkABf@303TaUYmHyo2DStYVwKnQCkQhE@vXcHvM26n7ic5jMO6zTpmv4g4EoZ7HmIT5WQgpBF90MLQ6FQnoJ/ouKw7R8eXtYpHCm5s6Ay/6Wrn1I4d6P@@RaebNhpkp2pj9qTZC0JaLNLVNUx3mOlAi/geTsw2TsQx/OPh46mAxFoEGw@NLz3VdCCdwBYZqVCT/ir@UDB8jI0YNb5EBGDn44dPnTuCpmo4pDss6PujTF48dABwdnxz22Ayy46ilQ1uuh3k4CpdOGmfUAhhcqYZIcAbn7iUy1gWxOGFtw4pjJ9RMQDHeIy5GUFUSfKnzRjRfru0AkZRMqhSCNCUTXKZ4SMrozu4BMxv9E3DE5F@Ehco6sIYMVxGAAAnFDgzSMO@SU1K97AFrIctHVIYrBDWaZY61i3rNywl/qsIMOihK7mLhc1i4rjuHjGfzrvvHDP8q5EdAglbB0W1cptAm2l3ayy7uENbIaZLxUTKzbdpP7AiiuxxtcSBOORfbHLijRlvhwakPEOsdivVE64jZQBIyUvYiSTJ3Vla@rfwReP3mXfUGJU2KNeYaMBgNEH/BcrGMM9tY2OnkHeoVwKpgLkolxGPgu7u/0LzsLmzRkszA9Ck6BT0chKyDDR7AoXmgEa4BS6vwsmGS9QPqhfDEApJLukEPrUVUo4ZewHyzaalorDz5DTyJ/4A@Dk/7hp9btV2n28AWZrIN4MlGeMAqaZ0XA/6rNZSNYkMg68wnK1DnlPpiG2sQV0VoPN7lVWe5kQ6V6AV1h/Z2gYL1w7ApDHRC72OuC5mUdyqoeoHlJQ4zqfalEiZrlrkDMrdIFs4qFvBgiJsPkib2s0Yd63bpCjUYIHQi@twr6rdbyqzt170C7LFhxJk6arlh/qos1O7rmMBmT9rzbWMTB41R0dd2UzqFtIqZGyPQ2EXRdbfq@sS1FdFwP2BKuS@UY59MZ0bsE6FwGpNBoMjweXNER2GpHrI79foVm1x9R10culaHnqVMJdKvwYb/hvvY0tftFUK9ahMbWFiv4g089DZ4ENvfxMK8wbUeYQJTCQlAqbIpkQbWFVwGETQaDEifJIoq63o8CEbLWpJ480Ni3jQTs/1Doe1mob8TmzWHxBWD5nzTy5GkXbAesIGnWSYsUO/BcRx4cBQ9E@z/JHoPsmgNGwQIpXWHasZVlBPR/tiVXPucuppeQPy31w8EvSRX4CpBeRgrEXzHm8VdnMdWwbIFtNpJWiYZewgfgTc2XcDdtYxv4xxklosszsokxMsGHPgFe4jZXXgfA1AqQnjJ5mG2gvB5fI2z6N0NMg5UEBPFKi3xxwVaXOdFBRmYGLXkGmWmnIasqUd9LyPdlw3RsL0ayqV7fJhiCX0Er7NpGk/ZdWX2tdbyhN9E/2YsUjkzRmWDgRpzgrcktGeY/qw7jz0K1rX6iEmvlheDelbcZ@bh3zOPAYoO5Q9yXSYA@6zWT9Kkw4xsiDpcIakqsy/KBWK3AihKRrM0hkOJobWYLoZsHs@jJYZZxsbX@/@vK@M/wZWxcmWrwZdA@iJd2X@ZfbFqg8n4ep/VAL5G@KrObjXZWQ20eyrzmAq0ed0q/aEvTbVh35SUqUTLf/1v5GUOMtRo@ZE1NNG1bngdG1RZt/76p@87qgWuLjyIa9UuPToVEgY1ToKatJEmUQIR/b4WEyb/Du6JX8fMfrTmHWtocY7rzT1CDfl9f7hj0PJe3CwCoxHrmwVo8yqVyfuJo8/CTq3vvRBErykdrZc8v6nk7XDdB/haepcm/0NDhIbhE7ci0ncE3Q6ZvZEPHuKqfQ@bJGoQRPyLl/QgRF@eBFh9Gs9CSJLgmWpEkwxeJlP6rSmMSihT1nZkYWuKM5y9cNlFZboGQjcof2@Yh0mGPS0L89vIIaW9Hny/5/irFl1D8f87tkvW1G97z9//DQ)

Prints `-1<newline>`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, I love it.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
'@'' _@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X91BXV0h3uH/fwA)

Comment: Pretty sure `0 1 0` is shorter and also has three distinct characters (I don't want to repost my Jelly approach :P).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well though!. But that's just like your answerm so I'll leave this as is

Comment: Yeah, that's why I commented, didn't really want to post the same thing twice. (Hm... this might be the optimal solution for many languages.) Anyway, yours might be applicable elsewhere too!

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 21 bytes

```c
main(){puts("}u");;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/58rNzEzT0OzuqC0pFhDqbZUSdPauvb/fwA)

Comment: *Print the **last, middle, and first** character of your program's source code, **in that order**.* You're printing first, middle, last!

Comment: oops, I just realized that.

Comment: If there is an even number of characters, you need two middle characters. (sorry ...)

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
[S aS S T   S S S S S N
_Push_32][S N
S _Duplicate_32][S N
S _Duplicate_32][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][T  N
S S _Print_as_character]
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@RobinRyder*.

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/XyFRQYFTAQS4gBCIOIEkDP//DwA) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

Contains a no-op `a` (can be any non-whitespace character) to make the length odd. It is added before the first halve of the program so the middle character is a space as well, since the middle character would have become a newline if it was at the second halve of the program. All non-whitespace characters are ignored in Whitespace programs.

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 7 bytes

```
.",  @0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X09JR0HBweD/fwA)

### Explanation

Output is `0 .`

```
.       pop value (0) from stack, output as number with a trailing space
 "      toggle string mode, wraps around and pushes every char to the stack
  ,     pop value (".") from stack, output as character 
        spaces are no-ops
     @  end the program
      0 trailing 0 to match the output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Full programs.

Boring solution from J.Sallé:

```apl
1231
```

Prints that number. A much more interesting solution:

```apl
010E1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@BoYGrIYj5XwEMCgA)

APL ignores leading zeros, so this is simply scaled format for 10×10¹=100.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 11 bytes

```
(((())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@fUQMIGDWBgPH///@6jgA)

### Explanation

We need to put 3 things on the stack.  The fastest way to do that is to put 3 1s (or zeros) on the stack.  Now since  (code point 1) does nothing in Brain-Flak we can add these to the program at the first middle and last places.  Now this feels a bit cheaty so here are two more answers that are less cheaty in my opinion.

## Prints braces, 31 bytes

```
( (((((()()()()()){}){}){}))())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0EDDDRhULO6FopAnP///@s6AgA)

This answer prints braces so that the characters printed are actually relevant to the code, it does have one padding character to make the length odd so we only have to print 1 middle character.

## Contains only braces, 32 bytes

```
(((()((((()(()()){}){}){}){}))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwg0NaCkpoamZnUtAgHB////dR0B)

This is a braces only program both the source and (consequently) the output are made up entirely of braces (character Brain-Flak actually cares about).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <strike>19 bytes</strike> 13 bytes

```
print( ')(')
```

The print function appends a newline by default so the code starts with a newline. The last character of the code is a ")" so that's printed first. To make the number of characters uneven, a space in inserted before the argument of the print function. Please excuse the salaciousness of the code.

Outputs: `)(\n`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9YtqCyo/P@fq6AoM69EQ0FdU0Nd8/9/AA)

Comment: Depending on how the rules work I might have 13 bytes playing with your answer:  `
print(")(" )` Note there is a new line above `print` and a whitespace inside `print` after `")("`.  Outputs: `)(
` with a new line at the end.

Comment: Thanks, down to 13 bytes! As the question specifically refers to whitespaces but not newlines I'll assume trailing newlines, as the default `end` parameter of the print function, don't count.

Comment: This prints a trailing newline but doesn't account for it.

Comment: Not sure if newlines count as whitespaces but I added the 2nd also 13-byte version.

Comment: Yes, newlines count as whitespace, just like tabs and spaces among others

Comment: Thanks, removing the now redundant upper part of the submission.

Comment: This gives the wrong middle character. I think you need to swap the `(` and the previous space.

Answer (score 4):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 9 bytes

```
a"a\\a"pa
```

The a's do nothing here, they're essentially NOPs in this code to make it shorter. My original thought was `"p\\\""p`, but that's 8 bytes, so it needs to print another `\`, making it 10 bytes `"p\\\\\""p`

This is a language I did create, but I made it legitimately, so I hope it's within the rules.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
"¨ ¨"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X@nQCoVDK5T@/wcA) In Husk, `¨` is the escape character for `"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
main=putStr"\"Sm"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIKUYpOFfp/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 11 bytes (as lambda function)

```java
v->'"'+"'v"
```

Outputs `"'v`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU1LCoMwFNx7isFNIkUvUNob1E3BTeniNdoSG59inoFSPHsaqZuB@fcUqOzbdzSOvMeFLH8zwLJ085NMh3qjwFVmyy8Y3Yy2RSiOSV2zBF5IrEENxgkxlGeVq0OuQh63yLQ8XHL3UNi6Q7rQ/7nbHVTs@x8v3VCNi1RTssSx5spoXpwr9rM1/gA)

## Java 8, 67 bytes (as full program)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]ar){System.out.print("}ni");}}
```

Outputs `}ni`.

Note the `ar` instead of `a` as argument. Otherwise the middle part had to be `in`, but printing that would make the size odd again, which would cause a paradox-loop..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z8zryS1KC0xOVXBt7q4JLEkM1mhLD8zRSE3MTNPI7ikKDMvPTo2sUizOriyuCQ1Vy@/tESvAChaoqFUm5eppGldW/v/PwA)

Comment: @racraman Please don't go edit other peoples answers. If you have a golf to suggest, leave a comment stating so. Also, your golf on my answer was incorrect. Your code would output `vv"`, but it's supposed to output it in reverse, so it should have output `"vv`.

Comment: -2 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235169/106557

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
1231
```

-1 byte by using the trivial solution presented by [*@ErikTheOutgolfer* in his Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188019/52210), which works for any language with implicit output without trailing newline.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/QyNjw/38A)

**Original 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) answer:**

```
ùù xx
```

Outputs `x ù`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wzsM7FSoq/v8HAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ùù x   # Push 3-char string "ù x"
    x  # Reverse it to "x ù"
       # (output the entire string joined together implicitly without trailing newline)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 11 bytes

```r
cat("))c" )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRENJUzNZSUHz/38A)

Outputs `))c`. Space added to make the number of characters odd: otherwise we would need to output 4 characters, and that would make the code longer anyway.

Comment: Is this allowed? https://tio.run/##K/r/3y/R7/9/AA  If so, you can cut it down to 3 bytes...

Comment: @Sumner18 I don't think it's allowed, because the initial `[1]` in the output counts. And maybe the trailing newline as well...

Answer (score 3):

**HQ9+ 4 characters**

`+AQ+`

Explanation:

```
+ ; increment accumulator
A ; nop
Q ; print itself
+ ; increment accumulator
```

Comment: *`Code must consist of >= 3 distinct characters`*

Comment: @Draco18s thanks, I missed that part of the rule. I think I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 9 bytes

Prints an escape-supporting string.

```forth
.\"   ."
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//68UoKSgo6Ckp/P8PAA)

---

#### Also 9 bytes:

Prints three spaces.

```forth
 ."    "
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//K@gpKQCBksL//wA)

---

#### 9 bytes with Stack Underflow:

```forth
 ." .. ".
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//K@gpKejpKSjp/f8PAA)

---

The 2nd and 3rd solutions also work if you replace first quotations with `(` and last quotes with `)`. Essentially, plenty of ways to do it in 9 bytes, but probably not any shorter.

[Documentation](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Displaying-characters-and-strings.html)

Answer (score 3):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 65 bytes

```
PLEASE,1<-#3DO,1SUB#1<-#246DON'TPARSE!!
DO READ OUT ,1
DO GIVE UP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FXH0EZX2djFX8cwONRJGcQxMjFz8fdTDwlwDAp2VVTkcvFXCHJ1dFHwDw1R0DEEcd09w1wVQgP@/wcA)

Padding the second half of the program to make the output `PPP` seems to be shorter than printing multiple distinct characters.

```
PLEASE ,1 <- #3         Declare that the length of the uint16 array ,1 is 3.
DO ,1 SUB #1 <- #246    Make the first element of ,1 246. (The other elements are 0.)
DON'T PARSE!!           This statement is ignored and nonsense.
DO READ OUT ,1          Print ,1 using C-INTERCAL's "Turing Tape" I/O.
DO GIVE UP              End the program.
```

This one *almost* works for 35 bytes, but it prints a space before the first newline:

```
PLEASE       READ OUT#500DOGIVEUP
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 13<s>15</s> bytes

```
disp(  ') d')
```

Outputs `) d`

Previous version (15 bytes, less strict output):

```
'''';1;''''''''
```

Outputs `'''`

Comment: I see now, now worries.

Comment: Doesn't this output trailing whitespace?

Comment: @Sanchises nope, size(ans)==3

Comment: Yes, but the actual output is `ans =\n    '''\n`. Usually that's not a problem but this challenge seems to set a stricter standard. But then I may be interpreting the challenge wrong.

Comment: @Sanchises hm, i see. i might misunderstand what codegolf considers "output" then, your output seems to be literally the output, formatted by MATLAB

Comment: @Sanchises i have added shorter version, that seems to comply. Could you please check? I like the original more though :)

Comment: @aaaaaa `disp` also has a trailing newline. But maybe instead leave the old version and ask if that's OK. I guess this challenge is a little bit unclear because it seems to deviate from the standard but doesn't explicitly say so.

Comment: @Sanchises `fprintf( ')(f')` should work, as it outputs no trailing whitespace

Comment: Yeah I posted that as an Octave entry.

Answer (score 3):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronjanse/asciidots) - 9 bytes

```
.---$'.$.
```

Output: `.$.`

The code starts with a `.`, ends with a `.`, and the middle character is a `$`.
The single quote in the middle sets the dot print mode to simply read characters straight into the output stream.

It is possible that this could be made smaller, but I'm starting to doubt that it can. In order to print three characters, the single quote must be used, as the double quote would require an end to the string in order to output. However, this means that the single quote has to a) be followed by three characters and b) cannot be the center character. In order to crunch this down to seven bytes, I was considering trying to reuse the dot's start as one of the printed characters (sort of like AsciiDot's quine program). However, I found that the shortest sequence available for printing was `($'` which would have had to print four characters in the space of three, or three characters in the space of four. I also tried some hacky alternative methods like trying to print the dot's value (which is 0) as one of the characters. While there may be some system that works, I've found these to be rather complex and large. Thus, I think that the above is the smallest solution. (I will update if I find something smaller)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! I messed around with this for a few minutes and came to the same conclusion you did. Nice first post!

Comment: Alternative 9 bytes - `/'$'-.[newline]\.`[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fX11FXVePK0bv/38A "AsciiDots – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <del>7</del> 5 bytes

```
".".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/n0tJT0nv/38A)

### Explanation

```
     # A newline, just to hide the effect of the automatic trailing newline
"."  # The . character: the last and middle character
   . # Copy the character twice

# Implicitly output the whole stack without a delimiter.

# This returns ".." (the . character duplicated) and a trailing newline.
```

Comment: There is a trailing newline at the end of the output; I'm not sure that's allowed. There is a boring 5 byte answer which only outputs 2 spaces and a newline: [TIO](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/n0tJQUnh/38A "GolfScript – Try It Online").

Comment: @RobinRyder No, it doesn't. It just outputs a single space and a newline. (TIO renders a newline as a space.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 5 characters (6 bytes)

`×'×3×`

[online interpeter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=1yfXM9c=)

### Explanation

```
×'×3×
×     ; call × on the first two arguments (0 by default) and ignore the result
 '×   ; the character ×
   3× ; repeated 3 times
```

Answer (score 2):

### AppleScript, 4

```
1021
```

Outputs the last char (`1`), the middle chars (`02`), and the first char (`1`).

Any four-digit number with the same first and last digits and different middle digits works.

Comment: 2 Distinct characters are a requirement

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Does this edit qualify?

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 11 bytes

```javascript
_=>(')\)_')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k5DXTNGM15d839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Comment: My approach: alert(")\"a") - sadly 2 Bytes longer with 13 Bytes

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k7J2jpeyfp/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoam5n8A) using a similar trick you used in your PHP solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>39</s> 25 bytes

```
fun main(){print("}rf")
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvREOptihNSZOr9v///4lJySkA)

Edit: -14 bytes thanks to @daniero

Comment: `main` doesn't need parameters, you can drop 15 bytes

Comment: @daniero Cool, didn't realize that - thanks! (Only dropped 14 bytes and added an extra new line because if otherwise id have to print 4 characters) Also kinda cool that just by chance it still had the same output

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```powershell
' D'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0tdwUVdQeH/fwA)

Notice the two spaces after the last quote. Forgot that using implicit output puts a newline afterwards. Fixing that saved a byte though.

### Alternative 7 byte solution with 3 unique chars by mazzy

```powershell
"`"`""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0spAQiV/v8HAA)

Comment: Actually, `1231` doesn't work since PowerShell outputs a trailing newline by default. `1231` only works in languages with implicit output without trailing newline.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah, didn't even think about that even though my current answer takes it into account. Purge inbound.

Comment: it seems to me that the output should be `'''LF` for this source code

Comment: @mazzy One day I'll post an answer that's up to spec.

Comment: nice. [7 bytes, 3 unique chars](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0spAQiV/v8HAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
⎕←'''''⎕'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE9RBAMhU//8fAA)

Both the last and middle characters are `'`, while the first is `⎕`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
.PPP
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%0A.PPP&i=)

The leading linefeed does nothing. `.PP` pushes the string `PP`, and the final `P` prints it with a trailing newline. The last character is `P`, the middle character is the first `P`, and the first character is a linefeed.

The implicit print's trailing linefeed invalidates the 4-byte solutions `1231` and `.S.S` (adapted from [Weijun Zhou's quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156643/73884)).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 <s>12</s> 13 bytes

```
input(r')ri')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 13 bytes

```forth
: f ." ; :" ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKegpKVgrWAGJ/2n/AQ)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f         \ start a new word definition
  ." ; :" ; \ print "; :"
;           \ end the word definition
```

Comment: You should add a footer, so people can actually see the output: https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKegpKVgrWAGJ/2n/AQ

Comment: Fixed, Thanks for the heads up, I totally forgot to call the function

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

```
⌋ ”⌋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/n@tRT7fCo4a5QOr/fwA)

The `⌋` is just there as a no-op.

```
            % helper function
⌋ ”⌋         % main function: push "⌋ " and convert to lowercase
            % then implicitly print with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
←´←´´´X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24RDW8AECEb8/w8A) The final `X` could be any byte in the Charcoal code page except `0xFF` and the two already in use. Works by printing the desired characters leftwards. Alternative approach, also 7 bytes:

```
←”y←←”y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24RHDXMrQRSE9f8/AA) The final `y` could be any ASCII character but I picked `y` because of the symmetry. Works by printing two `←`s leftwards so that the final character gets printed at the start of the output.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 7 bytes

Another trivial solution. The first and the last lines contains `LF`.

```powershell
"`nn"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0spIS9Piev/fwA)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 9 bytes

non-trivial, no byte sequence hacks. The first line contains `LF` only. The second line starts with a space.

```powershell
 echo hh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0shNTkjXyEj4/9/AA)

Comment: *Code must consist of >= 3 unique characters.* But: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188041/25180

Comment: thanks. i removed trivial solution with 3 non-unique bytes

Answer (score 2):

## dc, 9 characters

```
[PP]P91aP
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ dc -e '[PP]P91aP'
PP[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@r6yrq/uobTKE/B8dEBAbYGmYGPD/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

Inspired by [my JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188087/61613) solution.

```
N'a*N
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TidhKk4)

Comment: Ah-ha! I knew there had to be a 5 byter! Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
Print@nn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/58roCgzr8QhL@//fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 11 bytes

```php
<?=';\\<';;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5W3Tomxkbd2vr/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), <del>7</del> 5 bytes

```
1\':'
```

This prints `''1`, which are the respective characters.

No Try It Online available for Keg.

Here is an uninteresting 4-byte answer:

```
1231
```

Comment: Good to see Keg standing up to 05AB1E in code golf!

Comment: would `abca` also work as an uninteresting answer?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to keep this simple, so I will not add this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) (lambda expression), 17 bytes

```cpp
[]{return "}n[";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcExDoAgDADAva9odNHBDwDxI8SBVGKaQCVYJsPb0TsqZaMU5BozC6V2RnR8P1pjyDuwKObAsqzwAv4ePY2huyk6N/zx1qitCk5d/GT7WFYLHcYH)

---

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) (full program), <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```cpp
#import<ios>
int main() {std::puts("}n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//@fSzkztyC/qMQmM7/Yjiszr0QhNzEzT0NTobq4JMXKqqC0pFhDqTZPSdO69v9/AA)

Unfortunately had to leave an extra space in both of the solutions, to make them have an odd number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 9 bytes

```sh
<<<\<\<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@fi8vGxiYGCP//BwA)

Hexdump, with first/middle/last bytes highlighted:

```sh
00000000: 0a0a 3c3c 3c5c 3c5c 3c                   ..<<<\<\<
          F^        M^        L^                   ^   ^   ^
```

Output is `<<[newline]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bitwise Cyclic Tag But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Bitwise-Cyclic-Tag-But-Way-Worse), 26 bytes

```
ÿ1111111122ÿ2000000002ÿ
```

Outputs `ÿ ÿ ÿ`. 26 bytes since ÿ is considered 2 bytes in UTF-8.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S0ouSSov////8H5DKDAyOrzfyAAKgOz//wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 9 bytes

```
oN/
@oo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/58r30@fyyE/n@v/fwA)

Reasonably boring one.  Since the newlines in the first, middle and last positions are ignored by the interpreter the code wraps onto the following cube.  Spaces could be used as well. eg `oS/ @oo`

```
  o
N / @ o
  o
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Cm9OLwpAb28K&input=&speed=20)

- `N` Pushs 10 (newline) onto the stack.
- `/` redirects around the cube.
- `ooo` outputs the newline 3 times.
- `/@` redirects again and halts the program

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

```hs
main=($LT)print--L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/nys3MTPPVkPFJ0SzoCgzr0RX1@f/fwA) Outputs `LT<newline>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 71 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(){System.Console.Write("pa}");}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HSGOn9)
I don't think I need to explain anything here

Comment: The program should output the last, middle, and first characters, in that order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 21 bytes

```
v<<<<<>>>>>
>%?"v>@"@
```

Outputs: `v>@`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGBOxAgMtO1V6pzM5ByeH///@6jgA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGBOxAgMtO1V6pzM5ByeH///@6Yf91HQE).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

All arrows, including the `>v` in the string, will lead the path towards the leading `>` on the second line. From there the program flow is as follows:

- `>`: travel in an east/right direction
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `?`: Clean the top value on the stack. In some program flows it's highly likely we have a partial string on the stack, so we use this to wipe the stack clean of that potential string.
- `"`: Start a string, which means it will push the integer code-points of the characters used (rather similar as the Whitespace program).
- `v>@`: Push the code-points for these characters, being `118 62 64` respectively
- `"`: We're done pushing code-points of this string
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. Using the `-A` program argument flag these code-points will be output as characters instead.

Two things to note:

The top part could also have been `v<<<<<<<<` instead. Lost will wrap around to the other side when moving in a direction. So using `v<<<<>>>>` could be a slightly shorter path, and since it's the same byte-count anyway, why not use it. :)
Also, the first line contains an additional `<` and `>`. One of them is to avoid having the newline character as the middle of the program, which is rather difficult to output and would have only increased the byte-count. The second is to make the program length odd again, so we'd only have to output a single middle character instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

## 6502, 17/21 bytes

**6502: 17 bytes if running in zero page**

For initial testing I used [Py65](https://github.com/mnaberez/py65), a 6502-based microcomputer simulator written in Python. Starting Py65 with the command-line parameter `-o ff` moves the character output port to zero page address $FF, shaving three bytes from the code.

The program must be loaded and run at $0000, to guarantee outputing the correct three characters (in order) from the program with values `00` `B5` `A5`.

Here are the program bytes and their respective disassembly view in Py65:

```
.mem 0000:0010
0000:  a5  10  85  ff  a9  11  4a  aa  b5  00  85  ff  a5  00  85  ff  00

.d 0000:0010
$0000  a5 10     LDA $10
$0002  85 ff     STA $ff
$0004  a9 11     LDA #$11
$0006  4a        LSR A
$0007  aa        TAX
$0008  b5 00     LDA $00,X
$000a  85 ff     STA $ff
$000c  a5 00     LDA $00
$000e  85 ff     STA $ff
$0010  00        BRK
```

**6502: 21 bytes if running outside zero page**

Four additional bytes are required to allow the program to run outside of zero page. Three of the those bytes are the change in the LDA (load accumulator) instructions from zero page to absolute addressing. The fourth is the addition of a NOP (no operation) instruction, to maintain an odd number of bytes in the program.

This version of the program must be loaded and run at $0300, to guarantee outputing the correct three characters (in order) from the program with values `00` `00` `AD`.

Here are the program bytes (character values) and their respective disassembly view:

```
.mem 0300:0314
0300:  ad  14  03  85  ff  a9  15  4a  aa  bd  00  03  85  ff  ad  00  03  85
0312:  ff  ea  00

.d 0300:0314
$0300  ad 14 03  LDA $0314
$0303  85 ff     STA $ff
$0305  a9 15     LDA #$15
$0307  4a        LSR A
$0308  aa        TAX
$0309  bd 00 03  LDA $0300,X
$030c  85 ff     STA $ff
$030e  ad 00 03  LDA $0300
$0311  85 ff     STA $ff
$0313  ea        NOP
$0314  00        BRK
```

**6502: 21 bytes if running on an Apple II**

We've come this far, so let's plop this baby on an Apple II. I don't normally tote around my Apple //c anymore, so I used [a2ix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.deadc0de.apple2ix.basic&hl=en_US) on my Android phone.

Instead of sending characters to an addressed port, they will go to COUT (character output), a routine in system ROM.

$0300 is the usual spot for small assembly routines, so that's where I'll enter and list it. Running it yields a flashing space (`60`), inverse N (`0E`), and a normal " (`A2`). On the Apple II, ASCII characters are remapped across the 256-character range to achieve different character effects in text mode.

```
*300: A2 14 20 0E 03 A9 15 4A AA 20 0E 03 A2 00 BD 00 03 20 ED FD 60

*300L

0300-   A2 14       LDX   #$14
0302-   20 0E 03    JSR   $030E
0305-   A9 15       LDA   #$15
0307-   4A          LSR
0308-   AA          TAX
0309-   20 0E 03    JSR   $030E
030C-   A2 00       LDX   #$00
030E-   BD 00 03    LDA   $0300,X
0311-   20 ED FD    JSR   $FDED
0314-   60          RTS
```

Relocating this to a free area of zero page (good luck!) would not yield any byte savings. While the absolute indexed LDA (load accumulator) at $030E could be switched to its zero page indexed counterpart to save one byte, an NOP (no operation) would have to be added to avoid additional code to support print two middle characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
×'×3×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8HT1w9OND0///x8A)

```
×   push a string of nothing, repeated nothing times (in other words, push an empty string)
'×  push "×"
3×  push "×", repeated 3 times
    implicitly print top of stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, 17 bytes

```
BEGIN{print"}iB"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0SpNtNJqfb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
0a9a3a9m3a2o0a0a0a0a0m2o
```

**Explanation**

```
0a9a3a9m3a2o # Output "o" twice
0a0a0a0a     # Padding bytes
0m2o         # Output "0" twice
```

Original 28-byte solution: `0a9a3a9m3a1o0a0a0a9s5s1o0m2o`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry), 181 bytes

This program starts and ends with an upper case `L` and also has it in the middle of its source code. This golfed version is based off of the program that comes after it.

To try this online, follow [this repl.it link](https://repl.it/github/rojergs/brainetry), paste my source code in the `btry/replit.btry` file and hit the green "Run" button.

```
L b
a b c d
a b c d e f g h
a b c d
a b c
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e
a b c
a b c d e f g h L
a b
a b
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f L
```

The verbose version also starts and ends with an uppercase `L` and has one of those in the exact middle of its source code.

```
Lo and
behold: this program has
a self referential property! This code prints its
first, middle and last
chars! How nice!
Of course I cheated a little and made
this program in such a
way that all
3 of those chars are the upper case L,
which I
also had
to properly place in
the middle of this
text to make sure they appeared in those positions.
A bit of
luck and a bit of mathematics allowed
me to accomplish this feat. Let me
check it... Woops, missed by one... LOL
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 29 bytes

```
0 * 2 r 1
1 * 1 r 2
2 * 0 * 2
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?19e33279fce6c23fa252a858883367e8)

Prints '210'.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
5235
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/UyNj0/38A)

pretty simple, no explination needed

Comment: ah i see... i need to learn to read that English stuff 

Comment: @AaronMiller general question what should i do if a question is not valid? do i delete or leave it?

Answer (score 2):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 67 bytes

Outputs `n D`. Eventually I thought a space is really necessary.

```
D'`_$"\\[||98V6Bu@tOq<.'98*ZjE&fe {Ab~,v*)]xZvonsl2ponmfN+cba`ed]#n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/99FPSFeRSkmJrqmxtIizMyp1KHEv9BGT93SQisqy1UtLVWh2jGpTqdMSzO2IqosP684x6ggPy83zU87OSkxITUlVjnv/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 5 bytes

```
0p
n0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@ggCvP4P9/AA)

Pushes 0 to the stack, prints 0 with a new line, prints 0 without a new line and again pushes 0 to the stack.

`n` is a GNU implementation. Might not work with other versions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 15 bytes

This was surprisingly difficult. Outputs `a>=a`.

```
abc:
*=>a\>\=a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 115 bytes

```
   ^     ^
  / \   / \
 /out\ /out\
^-----^-----
-^   ^-
 -^ ^-
  -^-
  / \
 /chr\
^-----
-^
 -^
 / \
/32 \
-----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAwDATvecV@IBT0OyUgtVAPRal68PUxaekeZkMyub621WPnO5VcsyoAgUcICIjoJITzfeIgCXsGiV0XJtjgZc00n1JpUzfRHeqXsC7GvgdUfw)

The middle character is the space after the ^ on the fifth line. Prints three spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 9 bytes

```
print ptp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhYrC4oy80oUCkoKIHyoMEwaAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
R"R "
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbLuYKUghSUFCA8qCBMEgA) (Note the trailing space)

##### Explanation

```lisp
\nR"R "   ; Full program
\n        ; No-op
   "R "   ; The string "R "
  R       ; Reversed
          ; No-op
          ; Implicit output
          ; (with newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Elm 0.19, 11 bytes

```elm
f()="\"\\f"
```

Prints `"\f`. See it working [here](https://ellie-app.com/63vkRbXk6zLa1).

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
'@'':r@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/dQV3dqsjh/38A)

-2 bytes by just using char literals. Outputs `@''`

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 19 bytes

```
	OUTPUT = 'D='
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n4vTPzQkIDREwVZB3cVWncvVz@X/fwA)

Prints `D=<newline>`, using SNOBOL's trailing newline in `OUTPUT`.

`D=`

Answer (score 1):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), <s>292</s> 2340 bytes

*Thanks to Jimmy23013 for pointing out I need another 2048 bytes*

2340 bytes of any character with the first, middle two and last characters being a null byte.

Prints 4 null characters.

[Try it online in brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fDwj@/wcA)

Comment: @jimmy23013 ok should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
main=putStr"\"Sm"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIKUYpOFfp/38A)

Comment: Identical with [Damien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41073/damien)'s Haskell [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188018) posted almost 2 hour 50 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>31</s> 13 bytes

```lua
print (')(p')
```

Prints ***)(p***

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RBQ11To0Bd8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 7 bytes

```
01$*$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8BQRUtF5f9/AA) Retina 0.8.2 outputs a trailing newline by default, so the code starts with that. Conveniently, this also matches the default empty input, allowing the replace stage to get to work. It then suffices to come up with a string of even length > 2 that outputs the other 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 7 bytes

```
((K`(`(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0PDO0EjQeP/fwA) Retina 1 does not output a trailing newline by default, but fortunately it has the `K` command which allows us to specify a constant string output. The grouping construct `(` is used to increase the number of distinct characters to meet the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 22 bytes

```
	dot
	dot
0         0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/5@LMyW/BEIYKMCAwf//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
''ixi''
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=JydpeGknJw)

```
''ixi''
''          :Literal "'"
  i         :Prepend
   x        :  Literal "x" (any lowercase letter would work. Except i, of course)
    i       :  Prepend
     ''     :    Literal "'"
```

### Alternatives

```
"\"ww"w
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Ilwid3cidw)

```
Riii'R
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ClJpaWknUg)

```
"Q\""+Q
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=IlFcIiIrUQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
"w\\""w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X6k8JkZJqfz/fwA)

*Thanks to Shaggy for correcting this to comply with the challenge specification.*

Boring string literal, except thanks to the weird way Brachylog string literals work, the escaped backslash also still escapes the quote afterwards, so it's not actually that boring.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't read the spec closely enough. Thanks!

Comment: Coincidentally, I'd just added your original version as an alternative to my Japt solution - scrolled down and thought I'd found a polyglot!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 13 characters

```
\A=l\\\\@fail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfyvqAsCj9omw@j/MY62OTFA4JCWmJnz/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 bytes

```perl
say "\"\\s"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJBKUYpJqZY6f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Comment: This violates the rule "Output must not contain any trailing whitespace. However, if whitespace is a first, middle, or last character, it must be printed as such."

Comment: @Abigail That still breaks the same rule about trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML, 4 bytes

```html
^db^
```

```html
^<X>_<X>^
```

I'm not sure if this is cheating... Really.

First one also worked as PHP <s>or [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text)</s>.

Comment: It's my bad that not creating a page for [txeT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Talk:Text#txeT) before this challenge...

Answer (score 1):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 53 bytes

```
+>(-[!)
+"===#+
++
++
++
++
++
 +
)!)  <...
=#==="==+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9f205DN1pRk0tbydbWVlmbSxsVKWhzaSpqKijY6OnpcdkqA9UA1Wn//w8A)

Output: `+++`. The 27th character is one of the `+` characters in the second column of the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 8 bytes

```
1#11,2&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/31DZ0FDHSM3w/38A)

Outputs `11,1`.

## Explanation

```
1             Prepend 1 to the output
 #11,2        Default input is `11, 2`
      &       Output as many terms as the last input, comma seperated
       1      Each term equals 1
```

So first 1 is prepended, then the input becomes `11,2`. Then, we output 2 terms comma separated, which is `1,1`, so the final output is `11,1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>9</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

### First attempt:

```
echo e\ o
```

Output

```
e o
```

---

### Second attempt:

```
echo -n e-e
```

Output:

```
e-e
```

---

### Third attempt

```
    
echo  oo
```

Note the leading newline and the double space

Output:

```
oo
```

Comment: Welcome to codegolf.se. It should print in the order of the last, middle and first character, `o e` for your current code.

Comment: Also “Output must not contain any trailing whitespace.” I'm afraid your contains, actually outputs 4 characters instead of 3.

Comment: Now is correct, but became exact copy of [Grzegorz Oledzki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1104/grzegorz-oledzki)'s [Bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188065) posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle), 5 bytes

```
11!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/5/L0FDR8P9/AA)

Outputs `11` with a trailing newline. Only the first pair of `1`s is actually printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 27 bytes

```
HAI 1
VISIBLE "E H"
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8GQK8wz2NPJx1VByVXBQ4nLO8QjwinS9f9/AA)

Trivial answer in LOLCODE. The 14th character is the space just before the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 bytes

```perl
 say '; ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/59LoTixUkHdGoj@//@XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNAAAA)

Note the initial newline and the trailing space. Outputs

```perl
;
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 7 bytes

```
?":b?":
```

Output: `:b?`

(Probably works in most BASIC dialects)
The middle character can be anything except `"`,  LF, and CR.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 13 bytes (characters)

So many esoteric languages that seem to be made specifically for code golfing… let's try a terse but 'normal' language like F#, where the following line (without a trailing newline) has 13 characters (13 bytes if the source file is saved as ANSI text):

```
printf"\"\"p"
```

Output:

```
""p
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Boolfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck), <s>29</s> 21 bytes

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+
```

Outputs 3 null characters

Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for the improved solution!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#%23S8rPz0krTc7@//9dQ4M1DCCxtYHs//8B)

### [BitChanger](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BitChanger), 23 bytes

```
<<<<<<<<<<}<<<}<}<}<
```

Very similar to the Boolfuck one: uses the fact the null characters require no bit changing to output with tape-based bit output

### How it works:

```
           Used as it is simple to output
<<<<<<<<<< Moves over to one left of the I/O bit
}           Sets the I/O bit to one, for output
<<<         Moves over to the bit that performs I/O
}<}<}       Sets it to one 3 times, to output 3 null characters
<          I used < to waste one byte so it could be an odd number of bytes
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSc5IzEtPLfr//11Dgw0cADm1QKoWDIGc//8B)

Comment: Sure it matched the requirement “Code must consist of >= 3 unique characters.”?

Comment: Oh yeah, fixed it

Comment: Oh, didn’t realise that. Does it auto fill the last byte of output to 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
10 1
```

Prints `10` followed by a newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/n8vQQMHw/38A)

Newlines normally print the next result followed by a newline, but at the start of a program it is essentially a no-op. `10` is the literal value, which is printed followed by a newline. The space before the `1` suppresses the usual implicit printing, so the final `1` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

```matlab
fprintf(')(f' )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/raAoM68kTUM9TUNTXUHz/38A)

As far as I know, using `fprintf` is the only method of out that doesn't come with extraneous output.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>12 bytes</s> 11 bytes

```
Placeholder to make the leading newline visible

print"\"t"
```

Comment: This is 12 bytes and hence is even, so you must print the 6th and 7th character of your code, which is `' ' and '"'` so you should print `" "p` not `" p` like you currently do.

Also please consider adding a link to e.g. [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQSlGSaFA6f9/AA).

Comment: It also prints an extra newline, which is not allowed.

Comment: [This 11 byte solution may be valid](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/n6ugKDOvRClGqUTp/38A "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Do you agree? @jimmy23013

Comment: @ExpiredData Yes it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) (closure), 9 bytes

```rust
|| ";;|";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQ5qSUKaQq2/2tqFJSsrWuUrP@DRAuKMvNKcvIUNZSqa5V0FNI0NDW5av8DAA)

---

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) (full program), 25 bytes

```rust
fn main(){print!("}}if")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbY2M01Js/b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
O"}"xxL1{O"1O"}
```

Needs more golfing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fX6lWqaLCx7DaX8kQyP7/HwA)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
O"nn"x
n
```

shorter version with newline

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@fy18pL0@pgivv/38A)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
1x000Oh1
```

another one

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fsMLAwMA/w/D/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
…Lo…L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//1HDMp98EPH/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 5 bytes

```
/a//
```

Prints `/a` and a newline

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v@fSz9RX///fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## DOS COM x86 binary

```
% xxd test.com
00000000: 31c9 4b88 2f80 ffef 75f8 8007 30b4 028a  1.K./...u...0...
00000010: 17cd 2180 3f00 7503 e905 00fe 0fe9 f3ff  ..!.?.u.........
00000020: b402 8a17 cd21 8007 20b4 028a 17cd 2190  .....!.. .....!.
00000030: cd20 4b53 20                             . KS
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 (Mac OS), 35 bytes

```
b8 04 00 00 02 bf 01 00 00 00 48 be 20 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 ba 03 00 00 00 0f 05 48 31 c0 c3 00
b8 00 b8
```

can be disassembled to:

```
[bits 64]

section .text
  global _main

_main:
  mov rax, 0x2000004
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, x
  mov rdx, 3
  syscall
  xor rax, rax
  ret

section .data
  x: db 184, 0, 184
```

and compiled with:

```
$ nasm -fmacho64 FILE.asm
$ ld -fSystem FILE.asm
```

then run

```
$ ./a.out
<0xb8><0x00><0xb8>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 13 bytes

```python
print(')\'p')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ10zRr1AXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 13 bytes

This should suffice. Although it has a new line at the end of the output. There is a space in between print and '(' to make the total count of characters odd.

```python
print (')(p')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQUNdU6NAXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/w-golf/w), 5 bytes

```
'+:+
```

### Explanation

````
     % Newline (no-op)
'+   % The addition operator
  :+ % Multiply the character twice
     % Print with a newline
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 11 characters

```
57125574032
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M///39Tc0MjU1NzEwNjo/38A)

Prints `255`.

### Explanation:

The program pushes **`5|7255|4632`** onto the frame (which starts with `||`). Then, the last section of the frame (**`4632`**) is executed.

**`4`** swaps the last two sections, and adds another bar between them. The frame is now **`||5|4632||7255`**.

**`6`** *pacifies* the last section of the frame by converting the active commands **`7255`** (shown in **bold**) to their passive equivalents `1255`, and removing the bar before it. The frame now looks like **`||5|4632|`**`1255`.

**`3`** outputs the last section of the frame (`1255`) and discards the last two sections. The initial `1` means "print the rest unchanged", so `255` is printed. Then, the last two sections are discarded, leaving **`||5`** on the frame.

**`2`** duplicates the last section of the frame, leaving **`||5|5`**. There are no more characters left on the command list, so the last section of the frame (**`5`**) is executed.

**`5`** moves the last section of the frame (which is another **`5`**) to the start of the command list to be executed immediately, and then discards it. This leaves **`||5`** on the frame.

This happens again, leaving **`5`** on the command list and `|` on the frame.

The last **`5`** moves the last section of the frame (i.e. nothing) to the command list, leaving an empty command list and an empty frame. This causes the program to exit successfully.

#### Notes:

- The `57` at the beginning and the `2` at the end are included because without them, one of the first, middle, or last characters would have been a `7`, and printing `7` is hard.
- The program can fit into 4 *bytes*, but the question asks to minimize *characters*.

Answer (score 1):

## [Width](https://github.com/stestoltz/Width), 7 bytes

```
GAPSfeW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K89MKcn4/9/dMSA4LTX8/38A)

Outputs through STDERR.

I used a `G` to start the string. The ID of `G` is `39`, which turns into `eW`. The ID of `W` is `55`, which turns into `AP`. Then I just used `Ai` which is `50`, and checked how close it was to `A`, saw it became `R`, then used `Sf`, which is `51`, and becomes `S`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 13 bytes

`print(")\"p")`

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0kzRqlASfP/fwA)

Having `"` as the middle char is lucky, because then I can balance the parity of the code because it requires an escape sequence.

There's a few more Python 3 13-byters, so I imagine this is the shortest possible solution.
I don't there's a shorter solution with `exit()`, which prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 11 bytes

```
iq i`  wwwq        # Prints "q i"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 23 bytes

```
when gf clicked
say[wcw
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```lisp
(display "(y)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WikZBYX5CRWKihpVGoqaf7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 5 bytes

```
9C9$9
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=9C9%249&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
9            - Push 9
 C           - Set implicit output to number mode
  9          - Push 9
   $         - Swap the two nines
    9        - Push 9
<implicit>   - Output stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 5 bytes

```
 ‛‛‛
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%0A%20%E2%80%9B%E2%80%9B%E2%80%9B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Note the trailing space and newline.

Simply pushes `‛‛`, and prints with trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), 13 bytes

```python
print( ') p')
```

The last character is ')', the middle is number 7, a space and the first is the letter 'p'.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 13 bytes

most python answers work with julia too, but here are a couple very julian 13-byters

```julia
"s" |>show;""
"t|\""|>print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X6lYSaHGrjgjv9xaSYmLq6AoM68kJ09Dk4tLqaQmRkmpxg4s9P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

No flags used.

```
9 99J₴9
```

### Explanation

```
9        - Push 9
  99     - Push 99
    J₴   - Concatenate and print
      9  - Pushes another 9, but it never gets used.
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=9%2099J%E2%82%B49&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 13 bytes

```
print1(")("p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/v6AoM6/EUENJU0OpQPP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript II, 10 bytes

Welcome to Backslash Hell

`"\"\\\\\""`

I suspect that a shorter version is possible.

Comment: Would ` " a " ` with surrounding spaces be valid?

Answer (score 1):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 7 bytes

```
0..0#@0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/30BPz0DZweD///@6KQA)

The character that is easiest to print is the digit `0`. 5 bytes is impossible because it mandates three zero digits and a `@` at one of the two positions (2nd or 4th), which makes the program print 0 only once. For 7 bytes, we skip a 0 with `#` and print zero twice using `.` (explicit decimal output); the third copy of 0 is produced as the value that `@` evalautes to.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$7\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 5.76 bytes

```
Z" rr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLubiilBSKiiA8qCBMEgA)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188023/114446).

##### Explanation

```
\n\nZ" rr  
\n\n       # no-ops
    Z" r   # 2-char string: " r"
        r  # reverse to get "r "
           # implicit output with newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 25 bytes

```go
func()string{return"}nf"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BTcWCxOTsxPRUhdzEzDyuzNyC_KISBaW03BIlrrLEIoU0BdulpSVpuhY700rzkjU0i0uKMvPSq4tSS0qL8pRq89KUaiHyu0HyYEM0NKuB2vUCgApLNNI0NDWhKhYsgNAA)

Function which returns a string.

## [Go](https://go.dev), 35 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(){Print("} i")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjeVM3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jQ0qwOKMvNKNJRqFTKVNGshSjeAJUFagfJANVDhBQsgNAA)

Function which prints to STDOUT.

## [Go](https://go.dev), 51 bytes

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){Print(`}
p`)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjeNCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU0nJLlLjSSvOSwcIamtUBRZl5JRoJtVwFCZq1EK1QE2AmAQA)

Full program which prints to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

### Python REPL, 5 bytes

`122-1`

yields 121.

This probably works with many other interactive environments as well, but this is the shortest I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmoslang](https://github.com/theRealDadsdy/Desmos-Userscript/tree/main/Desmos%20Programming%20Language), 9 Bytes

```
1OOO1ETG1
```

Outputs 111

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 13 bytes

```swift
print (") ")
```

This is basically a Swift version of [this Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188007/118665) by [@TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld). Prints the last character `")"`, the middle character `" "` (a space), and the first character `"\n"` (a newline, printed thanks to `print(_:separator:terminator:)`'s default `terminator` of `"\n"`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 9 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 9 bytes.

- Filename: `O.ooo.o.O`
- Content: empty

Answer (score 0):

## [abcn](https://github.com/Muhammad-Salman-01/abcn-language), 15 bytes

```
a120gxgxnba98gx
```

### Explanation :

```
a120                  --> sets stack at 120
gx                    --> convert to ASCII and print (120 ==> x) as you can see x is last char
gx                    --> convert stack 120 again to ASCII and print `x` mid char (7th) is x 
                      --> as well (a120gxg make 7 and nba98gx make 7 so we print x)
b                     --> stack set to -1 (useless just made so we print x twice and 
                      --> not have to add more bytes)
a98                   --> add to stack 98 (giving us 97)
gx                    --> convert to ASCII and print (97 == a) a is first char
```

prints `xxa` which is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 9 bytes

```java
$->"  $"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDoJAEEV7TvFDKKCACxDtKaxMbIzFCEgGl2WzO5AQw9nXVYz6m0lm5v3X00x539x9rcg5HIg1HlGEENbS2hvVLaqwwidHsaw7kDFqSU8jN5iz8n1dN8xMV8U1nJCEMb8@htCabuD5ArKdy/4aKzB2Psn3MZDE8GX0ky1O2qEYJylMoEXplItNrSelsq959U8)

Comment: I'm not so sure that this a valid *self-contained* answer given that `;` is not part of the lambda ([I can't write `doSomething(v->";;v";)`, for instance](https://tio.run/##VYyxDoIwFEV3vuKFCUzgB2pYnI0Do3F4lIqv0pa0r10M316rk043uefeozFhp@dnzmQ25xl0KfrItPb3aCWTs/1BVHLFEOCMZOFVAWxxWklCYOQSydEMprBmZE92ud4A/RLa7xRgdqMzih@FNKkbaiFSLVpR2P5ReUrI6s/1@zg5G6JR/niZtJI8gCze8txzfgM)).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire [This is easily fixed by replacing all three `;` with a space, though.](https://tio.run/##XY7LCsIwEEX3fsXQVSo2/YBIl@5cFdyIi9iXqXmUZhIo0m@PsVZQVwP3zNwzPfc86@t7CEINZkToY0AdCklbpysURtMt21SSWwtHLjQ8NgCDu0pRgUWOcXgjalCRkRJHobvzBfjY2XRZBahNaVSDt0iIz4oEwCeQsoXl@T9lzCdsofNLNArPsfkxfV8c1h/3p0h28PYX0H7c5WSxUdQ4pLFKo9SkpXwY5ES0kzJdRXMITw) (Also, your TIO is incorrect. The `Consumer<Object>` should be a `Function<Object, String>`.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Possibly, but as is, it's not valid.

Comment: Thanks, replacing all with spaces seems like the best solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 67 bytes.

Outputs `1#D`. It was difficult to adjest program length. Eventually I decided to do `\#9`; this caused no side effects.

```
DO;1<-#9\#9DO;1SUB#1<-#100DO;1SUB#2<-#374DO;1SUB#3<-#276DOREADOUT;1
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

Answer (score 0):

## [FerNANDo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 53 bytes

Outputs `aaa`, but is it accepted...?

```
a a a
z a a z z z z a
z a a z z z z a
z a a z z z z a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0stykvMS8n//z9RAQi5qkCkQhUUEuT//w8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 9 bytes

```
'o:oo"'"o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1893yo/X0ldKf//fwA)

I had some more interesting versions (IMO anyway), but they were longer. :)

```
 'o         - push "o" on the stack
   :        - duplicate top of stack
    oo      - print both "o" chars
      "'"   - load a doublequote on the stack
         o  - print it
```

Prints output `oo"`

Answer (score 0):

## [DipDup](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/DipDup), 7 bytes

```
a[aaa]a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVRNj9owEL3nV0wjJBJRuPWClr0gKlVqVVR6i9KsN5hibWJbjilB6n@nM@N8LeVAxm/emy9PchbNm6yq@13V1jgPP2XrV3vhGum2pn5VWnjjmtUPKY77KDoKL5DiatjAFrZn4eAv7GDXWhdF/mYlm@jMiJRHkdKNF7qUcDiba1Bez9LJCPDXEJZsoUxJUeYTcAeSwDiLYbEImCQrzuOB9VU1HjnJYpHCCkqjS@G/Ccu@SWYq/TGzQ6zZO1miHoUYZ8bYvvCmOLBJioHbpXqghLZ7MqzXnGvPyUZ4Qy0@zZ6hEV41pxskL9r4XSXrF@wvj9MUG1tQy0R6lf4qpYakpOHOs3namzmafdY0pOVhD2m5nAHeQC30bWwl3N3Bi/INfUG5XAcAh3VSrYNPBNHolA/E9UjoIbypnJUDhDdv7ECF5XOohMCkZWpBd9l2G/L5omnsA7mLIf@Iqh8jP9FF1NHRL0UiKWg6cWxh/mtOrqOy7@EiwJcH@APD1jzAa4ZpIUa8QEQdQ339vPk5ra@b@KlSFlfxZKpjhRvFxz5QiDBV85QY3AANazUKmDIZMPZFSs5HdjfXG/83VHQwB20LDaouE9VlUDE/mB0QRdaMVLKTYqSim0Yy@PnwfwV4PXiCNu1jOtlthVP6d7hpshhX2l7ojSpFIyFr8SuStB8hjlN4Woa3M1ByMCd@C7M2pxD8JZhxn7hQ5CgIls4ZB7Gl71Y4xFFUC6WpgC/fIUnDCa9Se@lE6TGJvd9FJoTIxT8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>15</strike> 15 bytes

```python
print("  p")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0lBoUBJU0FB4f9/AA)

### Previous answer(Incorrect)

```python
print("pp ")
```

The answer is no longer pp （◞‸◟）

Comment: The question asks for last middle first, not first middle last.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks for pointing out, I have made the necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 41 characters

NB:
Despite appearing that way the source code has *no trailing newline*:

```pascal
program p(output);begin write('.gp')end .
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 bytes

```
` rr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS7kSFIqKlhQnJRdDRWAyAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer. Prints `r \n`.

**Alternative 5 bytes:**

```
12£1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy7gMjQ4tNlxSnJRcDBWCSQEA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's alternative 05AB1E answer. Prints `12\n`.

Answer (score 0):

### COBOL, 67 B

The [OpenCOBOL implementation](https://GNUCOBOL.SourceForge.IO/) does not seem to process non-lines (i. e. a character sequence that is *not* concluded by a newline character).
Therefore the COBOL source code contains *a* newline character.
However, I did not achieve printing a *leading* newline character (there was *a space* I could not get rid of).
So I extended the source code with some syntactically acceptable junk.
The `01` is *not* followed by a newline character.

```
000000 PROGRAM-ID.P.PROCEDURE DIVISION.DISPLAY"1I0"NO ADVANCING.
01
```

Output:
`1I0`